Question about Xavier Initialization for a Transformer model
I am coding since I was little but I started python recently and I am struggling to program a simple Transformer model that predicts the next word of a sequence. I am experimenting with max input sequence length set to 6 and token embedding size 512. When the user writes a new word, the program adds it to the vocabulary list and creates a randomly initialized token embedding. I am trying to do this with Xavier initialization but I don't understand what ninputs and noutputs are in the Xavier formula x=sqrt(2/ninputs+noutputs) where x is the uniform distribution for picking a random number. Would the ninputs and noutputs be the max sequence length(6) or the embedding size(512)? Sorry for my English.
I would appreciate it if someone could explain the 2 types of Xavier initialization (uniform and normal) and those 2 variables.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
